# Reading nested json in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to read a nested json data into a pandas dataframe. using the following code:

```
deptdata = json.loads(data)
print(pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(deptdata)))
```

The following output:

```
                           dept                      branchData
0                        Mechanical      [{'branch': 'abc', 'sale': 12}]
1                         Civil          [{'branch': 'xyz', 'sale': 18}]
```

If I use `pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(deptdata, record_path="branchData"))`, I get

```
branch       sale
 abc          12
 xyz          18
```

But I lose the dept details. How can I get both dept and branchData and groupby dept and branch ?

Answer (score 0):

a few ways you could do this, firstly I would read both jsons in seperate dataframes and concat if the indices match.

if that doesn't work, and your first input matches above we can use some string methods in pandas with the `ast` module `literal_eval` to read your string object as a dictionary and parse it out.

```
from ast import literal eval
df1 = pd.concat([df[['dept']], 
           df['branchData'].replace({'\[' : '', '\]' : ''} 
          ,regex=True).map(literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df1)

         dept branch  sale
0  Mechanical    abc    12
1       Civil    xyz    18
```